# Handling this Dynamic auto-suggestive dropdown in without list elements? selenium

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

As the application I work is in react, 
How can I handle this kind of dynamic dropdown without Html list elements? I can't able to inspect on the suggested options after it displays too.. is there any alternative approach to get the list of elements in the dropdown or only we can pass the required value directly for selecting an option from the dropdown..

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: sorry, will update it